# Mobile optimization - phone number

Tags: mobile

When mobile optimising a website, is there any html you should add to the site's phone number so mobile devices recognise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both iOS and Android recognizes phone numbers written in a sequence, like 070-112233, and makes them clickable. However if you use spaces, like 070 - 11 22 33, it won't always do that.

Comment: My windows phone emulator doesn't recognise 0845 123 4567 or  0845-123-4567, in both cases the 0845 is being left of.